# Scale first input video with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

Below is a command which I'm using to concatenate videos and apply a watermark. In that I want to scale my first video to 360⨉480:

```
"-i",inputFile1,"-i",inputFile2,"-i",watermarkImagePath,"-v","debug","-strict","-2",
"-filter_complex","[1:v][2:v]overlay=15:main_h-overlay_h[over];[over][0:a][1:v][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]",
"-map","[v]","-map","[a]",outUrl
```

Comment: Verify your command. In present command, first input's video isn't used.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't used your first input video at all. To scale it, use this in your filterchain:

```
[0:v]scale=360:480[v0]
```

Then use `v0` for further filtergraphs.

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted using the green checkmark next to it.